# Engine diagnostics after engine sucked in water

Tags: engine, diagnostics

I have a Great Wall V200 turbo diesel. I was four wheel driving one day when I went through a bit of water. The water came up over the bonnet due to the bow wave. After getting through the water, the car sat on flat dry ground and ran for about a minute. After that minute, it all of a sudden stalled. I knew that it may have sucked in water, so I left it and didn’t attempt to start the car. I removed the air filter, to find that the air box had a bit of water in it, and the air filter was drenched in water. I let it sit for about 10 minutes, then attempted to start it. It took a few goes to start it, but it eventually ran blowing white smoke (the water burning). It sounded like it was misfiring under 2000 RPM. Above that, it sounded normal. The smoke finally went away and I was able to drive out of the bush & home under my own power. When I got home, I replaced the air filter and ran it for a bit longer and it was still misfiring. I had a mechanic come look at it, and he said that my injectors were probably damaged. I got some injectors out of a mates v200 that’s timing belt snapped (the injectors were fine). I reinstalled the new injectors and the car ran rough for about a minute then stopped and won’t start since then. I do know that the injectors need to be programmed into the ECU which I am in the process of.

Is there anything else I need to check? Any sensors etc. I have taken the MAF sensor out and cleaned it, but it may also be damaged due to the water, but it should still run without it.

If you have any ideas or things I should check, that would be great :)

Comment: I don't see how water can damage an injector.

Comment: Not sure either, but that’s what he said. Sometimes water can make its way into the injector and ruin the internals.

Comment: Generally there are two issues associated with submerging the engine.  The most obvious is the ingestion of water into the intake and this almost always results in an immediate engine stop due to "hydrolock" where liquid water, which cannot be compressed, is in the combustion chamber and blocks the movement of the piston.  This causes things like bent connecting rod, broken piston, blown gasket, or a broken crankshaft.  The other main area is electrical where water enters wiring, connectors, or modules where it can and impacts the operation. It's hard to say which of these might have happened.